# Guardar resultados bucle en variables diferentes

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente bucle, y quiero que cada iteración se guarde en una variable diferente, que fuera por ejemplo, tabla_1, tabla_2... vaya el nombre es lo de menos

```
for(i in 0:20) {                 # Head of for-loop

  j=((i*12)+1)
  k=((i*12)+12)
  tabla_i <- round(cor(x = LAST_DFM[j:k, ], y = LAST_DFM[j:k, ], method = "pearson"), 2)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes guardar los resultados en una lista de la siguiente manera:

```
tabla_i = list()

for(i in 0:20) {                 # Head of for-loop
  
  j=((i*12)+1)
  k=((i*12)+12)
  tabla_i[[i+1]] <- round(cor(x = LAST_DFM[j:k, ], y = LAST_DFM[j:k, ], method = "pearson"), 2)
}
```

Donde `[[]]` es la manera de acceder a las listas, en este caso estaremos asignado los resultados a cada bloque de la lista

Observacion: en este caso partimos desde i+1, ya que las listas inician desde 1 y tu bucle comienza desde 0

Answer (score 1):

R permite la creación dinámica de variables, algo que es preferible evitar, en lugar de esto, la buena práctica es usar colecciones que puedan crecer dinámicamente como una lista, y dónde la referencia a cada elemento es mediante un índice (ver respuesta de Bastian). Dicho esto, y si ignoras la recomendación, puedes hacer algo así:

```
for(i in 0:20) {                 # Head of for-loop

  j=((i*12)+1)
  k=((i*12)+12)
 
  nombre_variable <- paste0("tabla_", i)
  assign(nombre_variable , round(cor(x = LAST_DFM[j:k, ], y = LAST_DFM[j:k, ], method = "pearson"), 2))

}
```

En este caso `assign(nombre_variable, valor)` puede crear una variable nueva con el nombre obtenido de la cadena `nombre_variable`, y que albergue `valor`.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción es usar `eval()` creando una cadena de texto destina en cada ciclo dependiendo del valor de `i`, pero como dijo Patricio mejor usar una lista como propone Bastian

```
for(i in 0:5) {

  j=((i*12)+1)
  k=((i*12)+12)
 
  txt <- paste0("tabla_", i,"<-round(cor(x = LAST_DFM[",j,":",k,", ], y = LAST_DFM[",j,":",k,", ], method = 'pearson'), 2)")
  eval(parse(text=txt))
}
```